# Woocommerce custom field calculation

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic

currently I am trying to build a small online shop for our printing company. I am trying to get this done with woocommerce. I am using variations to get options like A4, A3, A2 or b/w, color. Furthermore I bought the plugin Extra product options to have a multifile upload and checkboxes,ect.

But what if someone has different paper dimensions like 500x200mm? How can I add a field with length and height, which then multiplies itself with our sqm price?
E.g.: 0,5m x 0,2m *5,20€= 0,52€ * product options.

Is there a way to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :)
(not affiliated in any way)

https://woocommerce.com/products/measurement-price-calculator/

It is a bit pricey though, so make sure to check the live demo before buying. If you need a hand setting it up, lmk - don't mind lending a hand.

Comment: Well this looks to be my "go to". As I am a student and developing for a family company, I can't afford that yet. So I think I will go with the base formats or write a small plugin myself. And then if the shop made the money for the plugin I am going to purchase it. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MarcelLein For sure - also just wanna point out that legal services like gplvault (google it) do exist if you're on a tight budget. You don't get support or automatic updates (main thing that you're paying for on the WC site), but in terms of the plugin code and in terms of the legality of it, it's pretty solid (since the items fall under the GPL license). Good luck with your studies and glad to have you aboard the dev train :)